# Exporting key value pairs in CSV using Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to export a java object into CSV file using Camel CSV documentation. I can see example

```
Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<String, Object>();
body.put("foo", "abc");
body.put("bar", 123);
```

... through this route ...

```
from("direct:start").
marshal().csv().
to("mock:result");
```

This prints `abc,123`
But i want both keys and Values in my CSV. Can you please help me on this..

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the option `autogenColumns` to `true` so the keys is outputted as well. Read the documentation

- https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/dataformats/csv-dataformat.html

Comment: How to do this as of 2.15?